# sprintf with empty parameters detect

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements, printf

I'm trying to prepare  element for HTML page with search results. User can provide various criteria to search form e.g. city, region, type. User can provide each or none of criteria. I want to generate title depending on selected criteria.

My code:

```
$criteria = array('city' => $_POST['city'], $region = $_POST['region'], type => $_POST['type']);
$titleBase = 'You are looking for %s, %s, %s - mySite.com';
$title = sprintf($titleBase, $criteria['city'], $criteria['region'], $criteria['type']);
parse($title, '<title>');
```

Effect:
*You are looking for city, region, type - mySite.com*

It's good, but what if user not provide "region" and "type"?  I would have:
*You are looking for ,, type - mySite.com.*

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of possible approaches, starting from very targeted fixes and generalizing as you go.

The simplest that should work is something like this:

```
$lookingFor = implode(', ', array_filter($criteria));
$title = 'You are looking for '.$lookingFor.' - mySite.com';
```